# How to create a dynamic struts2 form (depending on values in the action class object)?

Tags: struts2

I want to create a dynamic struts2 form.

I have an `index.jsp` which accepts counts for 4 fields. I save this into a model object and navigate the user to the next page where the form will be generated depending on the counts they entered in `index.jsp`.

I can implement it using JavaScript but I cannot use JavaScript (no guarantee of it being present on client side). So, how do I do that.

[This is the form which accepts the counts](http://imgur.com/1p67qw7).
The generated form should have n IPV4 fields, n URL fields, n MACADDR fields and so on.

Is there a way to do this in plain Struts2 without using any external frameworks or JavaScript.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @RomanC Well, you are correct, it seems the answer is very long for this format. And being more specific doesn't help. I guess I'll come back and write an answer myself later.

Comment: Please see if I get you correct. You mean users enters a number for example `6` in `index.jsp` and hit enter button. The next page will be generated. This page should have `6` sets of inputs.  For example `No 1 IPV4 address`. `No 1 MAC address` ..... `No 2 IPV4 adderss`, `No 2 MAC address` .... up to number 6. Is it what you want?

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi Exactly. I got it to work and if you can explain it in a good answer it would be great. Otherwise I will eventually add an answer myself as soon as I get some time.